# Unable to query PostgreSQL with Apache Drill 1.11, VALIDATION ERROR

Tags: apache-drill, validationerror

I managed to connect Drill and PostgreSQL but even for a simple command like `show tables` I am receiving:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: VALIDATION ERROR: Multiple entries with same key: campaign_items=JdbcTable {campaign_items} and campaign_items=JdbcTable {campaign_items}
```

I have two schemas `public` and `fdw` which contains the same table name `campaign_items`. How can I force Drill to use the fully qualified name to avoid confusion? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To use `show tables`, you need to select the schema first:

> First issue the USE command to identify the schema for which you want to view tables or views. For example, the following USE statement tells Drill that you only want information from the dfs.myviews schema:
>
> ```
> USE dfs.myviews;
> ```

https://drill.apache.org/docs/show-tables/