# Drill ERROR: Multiple entries with same key

Tags: apache-drill

Selecting from Postgresql RDBMS plugin causes this error in combination `WITH` clause.

```sql
WITH src AS (
    SELECT "ArticleId", "Test"
    FROM dfs.test."SomeParquet" 
    WHERE <...>
    )
SELECT "Id", "Name" from postgres.test."Articles" a 
JOIN src s ON s."ArticleId" = a."Id"
limit 10
```

> VALIDATION ERROR: Multiple entries with same key: CategorySettings_CategoryId_key=JdbcTable {CategorySettings_CategoryId_key} and CategorySettings_CategoryId_key=JdbcTable {CategorySettings_CategoryId_key}

- The affected table (CategorySettings) isn't referenced in the query at all.
- Joining the parquet directly without `WITH` clause works.
- `USE postgres.test` does not have an effect [(inspired here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149236/unable-to-query-postgresql-with-apache-drill-1-11-validation-error).

There are multiple schemas in the `postgres` namespace, all of them have same table structure.

How to get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error should be fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-7415. Please check current master version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just for my information - How much stable can this master be considered? I have bad feeling about putting a pre-release version in our stack. Also - is the release date for 1.18 already known?

Comment: Actually, tried this in version 1.17 and there it already works, too.